# Domain driven design: How to add a new database entry for an Aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

In Domain Driven Design, what is the best way to create the database entry when a new object is created inside an Aggregate?

As an example, consider a `Student` entity representing a student at a university. The student takes courses, and these are part of the student aggregate as a list of `CourseParticipation` value objects. Those objects track the student's participation rate and final grade. When the student registers for a new course, we call `Student.participateIn(Course)`. In Java, it looks like this:

```java
public class Student {

  private List<CourseParticipation> courseParticipations;

  public void participateIn(Course course) {
    // Business logic: Check if the student is allowed to participate
    
    courseParticipations.add(new CourseParticipation(this, course));
  }
}
```

Now the new course participation must be stored in the database in a table called `course_participations`. The usual way to do this in my application is to call `CourseParticipationRepository.save(CourseParticipation)`. How do I make this call when the object is created inside an aggregate?

Options I could think of or read on the internet:

**Inject `CourseParticipationRepository` into `Student` and save inside the `participateIn(Course)` method.**

Good:

- Clean interface of the aggregate: Callers just execute `student.participateIn(course)` and are done
- Enforces the rule that creating a new course participation *always* requires to a new database entry

Bad:

- The domain aggregate handles database concerns
- Injecting a repository into an aggregate feels weird. There could be thousands of `Student` objects ... is it a good idea to give each one a reference to the repository singleton?

**Return the unsaved `CourseParticipation` object and let callers save it**

Good:

- Database concerns are moved out of the domain layer into the application layer

Bad:

- The aggregate exposes its internals by returning the `CourseParticipation` object
- Every caller must remember to save the object
- Application logic is ripped apart; it is not obvious that a new course participation always requires to a new database entry

**Let `StudentRepository.save(Student)` make the call to `CourseParticipationRepository.save` for each `CourseParticipation` object**

Good:

- Database concerns are inside a repository, not the aggregate
- The internal `CourseParticipation` object is not exposed to the caller of `participateIn`

Bad:

- The `StudentRepository` needs access to the internal list of `CourseParticipation` objects, which would otherwise not be exposed
- The save method can become very complex if the aggregate maps to many database tables
- Avoiding unnecessary database calls (i.e., saving unchanged entries) can be hard

**Redesign the database tables or use an object database**

I read this advice in a lot of posts about Domain Driven Design. It makes sense for greenfield projects. But it is not an option for the application I work on.

What is the best or most common option? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agggregate shouldn't care about the table structure.  That (and the requirement that the aggregate is a unit of consistency) ultimately means that the third approach is the way.

> The StudentRepository needs access to the internal list of CourseParticipation objects, which would otherwise not be exposed

The list of course participations is part of the `Student`.  Saving the student implies saving the participations.

> The save method can become very complex if the aggregate maps to many database tables
> Avoiding unnecessary database calls (i.e., saving unchanged entries) can be hard

Them's the breaks, unfortunately.

It is basically the case that DDD aggregates assume an object store (or an event store, if event sourcing) in the sense that that abstraction matches the minimum functionality required for saving/retrieving an aggregate.  A relational schema, especially one which aspires to higher normal forms, is going to introduce overhead/complexity.